# Connecting ESP32 to AWS IoT via umqtt

Tags: mqtt, micropython, esp32

I have the following micro python code:

```
client = MQTTClient("youraccount/feeds/lights", "a21sigud7911d7.iot.us-west- 
2.amazonaws.com", user="None", password="None" , keepalive=10000, ssl=True, 
ssl_params={"certfile":"/49c84a8c4a-certificate.pem.crt", 
"keyfile":"/49c84a8c4a-private.pem.key", "ca_certs":"/root.pem"})


 client.settimeout = settimeout
 client.connect()
```

But when I run the script from repl on ESP32 i get:

File "umqtt/simple.py", line 61, in connect
TypeError: extra keyword arguments given

Any help please

Comment: Have you figured out?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ca_certs in the ssl_params dictionary.  Refer to [Micropython connecting to AWS with MQTT](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5166) and the [warning in ussl documentation](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/ussl.html).
Connecting to AWS using the ESP32 and the Micropython-lib MQTT is possible on the ESP32 because it used mbedtls.  However, it is not possible on unix/osx because it uses the axtls library - refer to this [issue](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/3151).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't trying to connect to AWS (but rather my own TLS secured MQTT Broker) – and I had exactly the same error message. In case anyone else finds this, when trying to solve that problem – the answer is actually really easy. You can't use the names of the files – but rather need their contents. So this worked for me:

```py
    from umqtt.robust import MQTTClient

    with open('device.key') as f:
        key_data = f.read()
    with open('device.crt') as f:
        cert_data = f.read()

    client = MQTTClient("ESP", "test.example.com", ssl=True, ssl_params={'key':key_data, 'cert':cert_data})
    x = client.connect()
    if not x:
        client.publish("Topic", "Hello World...")
```

You'll obviously need to replace "test.example.com" with the URL for your secure MQTT server...